# How to extract all urls having .html at the end?

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


r = requests.get("xxx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for link in soup.find_all('html'):
     print link
```

This not working for me someone can help?

Comment: you search on attribute, as most link are in href or src attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if '.html' in link['href']:
         print link
```

Comment: actually i want to retrieve all the urls ending with .html and when i print  link its empty

Answer (score -1):

you might want to use regular expressions and search for "href" attributes. Something like this to help you get started. Assuming you are searching all href attributes

```
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tags = soup.find_all(href = re.compile(r"\.html$"))
```

tags variable will be a list of all html tags whose href attribute ends in .html. Now, you can loop through tags and extract the href